# chrome extension develop - return url tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that has to check the url that is displayed on the current tab.

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (!(typeof tab === "undefined")) {    
            alert("the current url is"+tab.url);    
    }

};
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
    chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

The problem is that tab has undefined value when I change the focused tab from.

If I reload the tab, the correct url is returned in alert.

What may be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged` API is deprecated. You can use the [`chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) API instead:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
{
    if (!(typeof tab === "undefined")) 
    {
        alert("the current url is: " + tab.url);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo)
{    
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab)
    {
        alert("the current url is: " + tab.url);
    });
});
```